# Error updating aptly mirror Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, 18.04, updates, repository

I'm creating an Ubuntu 18.04 repository and I encountered this error while updating the aptly mirror.

```
Downloading & parsing package files...
Downloading http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz...
Downloading http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/universe/binary-amd64/Packages.gz...
Building download queue...
Download queue: 1 items (0.65 MiB)
Downloading http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/onedrive/onedrive_1.1.20170919-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb...
ERROR: unable to update: download errors:
  **HTTP code 401 while fetching http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/onedrive/onedrive_1.1.20170919-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb**
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this?